# How do i return all other results from a CASE statement

Tags: oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper, case-statement

i want my UCO column to show either a number 1 or 2, anything else i want to return the actual figure this could be any number figure. However currently it is showing and NULL because of my case statement.

Any ideas how to show the true figure?

```
SELECT S.STOPP_REAL_DELIVERY AS "Delivery Date",
  case when C.COLLECT_COLLECTED_QTY = '-1' THEN '1'
  when C.COLLECT_COLLECTED_QTY = '-2' THEN '2' END AS UCO
FROM MBR_COLLECT C,
  MBR_STOPP S,
  MBR_JOURNEY J
WHERE C.MARKET_CODE          = 'UK'
AND C.COLLECT_TYPE_CODE      = 4
AND C.STOPP_ID               = S.STOPP_ID
AND J.JOURNEY_ID             = S.JOURNEY_ID
AND J.JOURNEY_PLANNED_START >= '14-AUG-17';
```

Comment: you should add else

Answer (score 3):

Add an `ELSE` clause to the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT S.STOPP_REAL_DELIVERY AS "Delivery Date",
       CASE
       WHEN C.COLLECT_COLLECTED_QTY = '-1' THEN '1'
       WHEN C.COLLECT_COLLECTED_QTY = '-2' THEN '2'
       ELSE C.COLLECT_COLLECTED_QTY
       END AS UCO
FROM   MBR_COLLECT C
       INNER JOIN MBR_STOPP S
       ON ( C.STOPP_ID   = S.STOPP_ID )
       INNER JOIN MBR_JOURNEY J
       ON ( J.JOURNEY_ID = S.JOURNEY_ID )
WHERE  C.MARKET_CODE          = 'UK'
AND    C.COLLECT_TYPE_CODE      = 4
AND    J.JOURNEY_PLANNED_START >= DATE '2017-08-14';
```

Also:

1. Use the ANSI join syntax (rather than the legacy comma-join syntax) as it makes it much easier to see how the tables are joined and avoids errors from the old `(+)` syntax.
2. `'14-AUG-17'` is not a date literal - it is a string literal. Oracle will try to implicitly convert it to a date literal if you are comparing it to a date column but this will be done using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session variable as the format mask; this value is set **per-user session** and each user can change their own settings. If you rely on a default setting and the user changes it then your query will break (without having changed the query) for that user (and no others) and it will be very difficult to debug. Use an ANSI date literal instead `DATE '2017-08-14'` or explicitly state the format mask (and if you are using language specific month names then the language as well)  `TO_DATE( '14-AUG-17', 'DD-MON-RR','NLS_LANGUAGE="ENGLISH"' )`.